# Why setImageResource method is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-image

This is the first canvas:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/background_linen" >

  <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/girbaud1front" />

      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/girbaud4front" />

      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/girbaud2front" />

      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/TableRow6"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/TableRow7"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img4"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/girbaud3front" />

      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second canvas that image change will happen is this file:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/Layout01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:src="@drawable/girbaud1front" />

  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txt1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file:

```java
package com.example.flip3d;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Cards extends Activity {

  ImageView img1;
  ImageView img2;
  ImageView image;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cards);

    img1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img2 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View arg0) {

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myfirstimage);
        Intent startyou = new Intent("com.example.flip3d.FLIP3D");
        startActivity(startyou);
      }
    });

    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View view) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.may2ndimage);

        Toast.makeText(Cards.this, "Card Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent startyou = new Intent("com.example.flip3d.FLIP3D");
        startActivity(startyou);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

[My logcat message.](http://i820.photobucket.com/albums/zz130/lestah23/untitled-1_zps33fa9be5.png)

When I run this code on my phone. An error occurred and when I check the logcat it says: that I'm having error with `setImageResource();`.

What should I do? I'm a beginner in Android programming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add to your question the error in logcat.

Comment: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.may2ndimage); should work. Did you cleaned your project? Project -> Clean

Comment: Are ImageView img1, img2 and image, all are in Layout cards??

Comment: yes all of them ar in layout card

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Updated@

`Simon Schubert` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745966/646806) looks correct.

Otherwise you can also do by accessing getDrawable method from Resources.

```
Resources resources = getResources();
image.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myfirstimage));
```

Comment: Ok nice to see that you found a solution, how you solved it? What was the error?

Comment: Use ContextCompat.getDrawable or ResourcesCompat.getDrawable for API 22 and up

Answer (score 5):

1. Ok I saw your logcat image capture. Well done.
2. Check if the following ids exists in your `R.layout.cards`.

   ```
   img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
   img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
   image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
   ```

It looks like one of your images isn't accessable. What exactly is line 55?

3. Your code should work. I guess there is a bad reference in your R. Clean your project and recreate your R.

Eclipse: <kbd>Project</kbd> → <kbd>Clean</kbd>

Android Studio: <kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Clean Project</kbd>

Comment: Give Logcat with exception? how? :)

Comment: Go to DDMS -> Logcat -> select the error line "that i having error in setImageResource();" and press ctrl + c -> edit your answer and press ctrl + v.. or type it out. :)

Comment: there are a lot of different types of exceptions out there: for example the NullPointerException -> something isn't inited or do not exists

Comment: i try to clean my project but nothing happen. :(

Comment: this is the line 55

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.may2ndimage);

Answer (score 5):

`getResources().getDrawable` is deprecated.

You can try **`ContextCompat.getDrawable`**:

`image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.myimage));`

Answer (score 3):

You can also call **`setImageDrawable`** :

```
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myfirstimage));
```

Comment: check your view initializitaion properly.
Or show your view xml and logcat here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. Actually i find out that all my images were placed in /res/drawable. i had few pictures that were very big so i had to move them to /res/drawable-hdpi or xhdpi. Another trick is to shrink them down. I hope this will help someone. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
image.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myfirstimage));
```

1st line will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```
img.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.theResId, null));
```