# ImageView setImageRecource() chrashes app

Tags: android, imageview

When I try to reset the ImageView with 
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.swagimage2);
it crashes the program.

The original image is the same dimensions I'm trying to replace it with. When I made a new project it worked.

I tried what the responses suggested in this question, but it hasn't worked.
[setImageResource is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745864/setimageresource-is-not-working)

I tried using the other setImage methods but they didn't work. Is there something else I can try?

```
                    package com.example.swgalizer;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    double randomNum;   //Generates how many stars
    mainMethods mm = new mainMethods(); //Dialog methods
    TextView tv1;   //TextView for each star.
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5; 
    ImageView iv;
    TextView starText;
    Button button;

    int[] set;
    int setCount = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.swagimage2);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        set = mm.RandomSetDialog(this);
        TextViews();

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    //Sets swagbutton LongClickable
    public void addListenerOnButton(){
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.swagbutton);
        button.setLongClickable(true);
        button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                char[] inputArray = mm.getInputArray();
                randomNum = Math.random();
                TextViews();

                //ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

                //Toast.makeText(this,  a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                if(inputArray.length > setCount){
                    if(inputArray[setCount] == '1')
                        randomNum = .1;
                    if(inputArray[setCount] == '2')
                        randomNum = .3;
                    if(inputArray[setCount] == '3')
                        randomNum = .5;
                    if(inputArray[setCount] == '4')
                        randomNum = .7;
                    if(inputArray[setCount] == '5')
                        randomNum = .9;
                }
                if(randomNum < .2){
                    tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    //Set Visibility of text
                    tv1.setText(getStarString(1));      //Set text for text
                    starText.setText("1 Star Swag");    //Set num stars text
                    rb.setNumStars(1);                  //Sets num of stars
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.foreveralone);
                }
                else if(randomNum <= .4){
                    getStarString(2);
                    tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    starText.setText("2 Star Swag");
                    tv2.setText(getStarString(2));
                    rb.setNumStars(2);
                }
                else if(randomNum <= .6){
                    getStarString(3);
                    tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    starText.setText("3 Star Swag");
                    tv3.setText(getStarString(3));
                    rb.setNumStars(3);
                }
                else if(randomNum <= .8){
                    getStarString(4);
                    tv4.setText(getStarString(4));
                    starText.setText("4 Star Swag");
                    tv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    rb.setNumStars(4);
                }
                else if(randomNum <= 1){
                    getStarString(5);
                    tv5.setText(getStarString(5));
                    tv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    starText.setText("5 Star Swag");
                    rb.setNumStars(5);
                } 
                setCount++;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void TextViews(){
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
        starText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startext);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        tv3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        tv4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        tv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    //This method gets the text string for the star
    private String getStarString(int star){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if(star == 1){
            String[] star1 = {"You suck", "Solja boy has more swag then you!", "You trash ass nigga"};
            return star1[rnd.nextInt(star1.length)];
        }
        if(star == 2){
            String[] star2 = {"You suck", "Solja boy has more swag then you!", "You trash ass nigga"};
            return star2[rnd.nextInt(star2.length)];
        }
        if(star == 3){
            String[] star3 = {"You suck", "Solja boy has more swag then you!", "You trash ass nigga"};
            return star3[rnd.nextInt(star3.length)];
        }
        if(star == 4){
            String[] star4 = {"You suck", "Solja boy has more swag then you!", "You trash ass nigga"};
            return star4[rnd.nextInt(star4.length)];
        }
        if(star == 5){
            String[] star5 = {"You are amazing", "Still Great", "I'd give you a trophy if I had one"};
            return star5[rnd.nextInt(star5.length)];
        }
        return "idk";
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your logcat output say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first set the content view of your screen before accessing any of the UI elements. Just swap thing around in your `onCreate` function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //first show your layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //then retrieve UI elements and configure them
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.swagimage2);
    set = mm.RandomSetDialog(this);
    TextViews();
    addListenerOnButton();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the IV before setting the content view and before super.onCreate. Call it afterwards